# JSON is not parsing properly even though it should be correct

Tags: python, json

I am currently working on my NEA for GCSE Computer Science and I am trying to incorporate JSON into my project for easier access to the data later on.

I have tried running other JSON which seems to work, but for some reason the JSON that I generate fails to parse into a python list.

```py
with open('userProfiles.json', 'r+') as f: #Open up the json file for reading/writing.
    print(f.read()) # Debug message to check if f.read actually contains anything...
    currentProfiles = json.loads(f.read()) # Load the json into a useable list.
    print(currentProfiles) # Debug Message: So I can check if the list loads properly
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    password = hashlib.sha256((input("Enter Password: ")).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() # Create an sha256 hash to be used later to authenticate users.
    newUser = json.dumps({'users':[{'username':username, 'password':password}]}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    f.write(newUser)
```

Here is the JSON file it generates when I comment out the load code

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "password": "8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918",
            "username": "Admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to load this JSON into a list so I can extend it with another user when I need to, but I can't due to the error message:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

When ever I attempt to parse the JSON, I have run the JSON through an online verifier that tells me it is valid JSON. I can not seem to find the problem here.

Comment: `.read` will *consume* the iterator, so there's nothing left the second time you do it. Do e.g. `content = f.read()`, then you can `print(content)` and *still* `json.loads(content)`; the string doesn't get consumed.

Comment: its amusing that a so-called "debug" message causes the bug.

Comment: I see, didn't realise that. I've got it fixed now thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `read()` reads through the entire file and leaves the read cursor at the end of the file (with nothing more to read).

```
with open('userProfiles.json', 'r') as f: #Open up the json file for reading/writing.
    data = f.read()
    print(data) # Debug message to check if f.read actually contains anything...
    currentProfiles = json.loads(data) # Load the json into a useable list.
    print(currentProfiles) # Debug Message: So I can check if the list loads properly
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    password = hashlib.sha256((input("Enter Password: ")).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() # Create an sha256 hash to be used later to authenticate users.
    newUser = json.dumps({'users':[{'username':username, 'password':password}]}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

with open('userProfiles.json', 'a') as f:
    f.write(newUser)
```